# SARS-CoV-2 proteome: is the SPIKE protein not an issue for a hospitalized patient?

Tags: virology, protein-binding

I am performing molecular docking of ligands using the modeled proteome of SARS-Cov-2. My question is, after a patient is hospitalized, is the SPIKE protein not really an issue anymore, since its role for binding with ACE2 has already been carried out?  Or, is SPIKE an ongoing issue that is not only an early event in the causal pathway?

Rationale is that SPIKE is quite large, and takes more than a minute of run-time per ligand -- thinking about excluding it to speed up runs.  NSP15 is also another "larger" protein, but I know NSPs are translated inside infected cells - so should be included in docking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a problem. "The virus" is not a single particle that only needs to enter a single cell, a single time. It is a population of millions of viral particles, that infect millions of cells. So, as long as there are more cells to infect, the viral population still needs a mechanism to enter the cell (i.e. it still needs all the proteins needed to function).

Comment: thanks for the rapid response.